# What could produce this debugger behavior when using try-catch without an Exception variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception

In a certain part of code there is a

```
try {
  a_function()
} catch {
  do_stuff()
}
```

which in about 1/3rd of software runs, it makes Visual Studio's debugger to break with a cryptic "*Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code*" (exception settings are all default).

The debugger's break appears to happen before do_stuff() has a chance to be executed.

Now what is very peculiar is that if I instead do

```
try {
  a_function()
} catch (Exception ex) {
  do_stuff()
}
```

The program runs correctly without breaking at all! That assumes a_function() does not throw a regular Exception.

Now, I was tempted to say that it might be an issue with more generic exceptions that do not inherit from Exception, but what's even more peculiar is that if I instead do

```
try {
  a_function()
} catch (Exception) {
  do_stuff()
}
```

(i.e. without the "ex" variable)

The debugger returns to the initial issue and breaks again cryptically!

What could produce this behavior?

Comment: Do either functions perform any type of asynchronous operations, be Threading, Tasks, Parallel, etc.?

Comment: Yes, BeginRead() is used.

Comment: It also has nested try-catches which remove the problem if they are removed.

Comment: A lock{} encompassing try{} prevents the issue and on another machine Visual Studio does drop into native threading code. It's definitely related to asynchronicity.